# afnvision:// URL Scheme

Tags: ios, url-scheme

iOS application is calling following error:

> -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "afnvision://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme afnvision"

I have looked `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` and all calls to `canOpenURL` , but can't find such a url scheme any where. I have not added this url scheme in my app.

I feel appsFlyer is calling this. Because I get two logs

> [1669:49374] AppsFlyer SDK version 2.5.3.16 started
>
> [1669:49374] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "afnvision://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme afnvision"

Anyway I can stop this or know which all URL schemes my app calls when it is on App store.

Comment: Have you added 'afnvision' to your LSApplicationQueriesSchemes?

Comment: @Paulw11 ...  No. I have not added any such scheme anywhere in my app. I feel appsFlyer is calling this. Because I get two logs 

[1669:49374] AppsFlyer SDK version 2.5.3.16 started
[1669:49374] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "afnvision://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme afnvision"

Comment: So either add this to your info.plist if you want the framework to be able to check for that URL or don't and just ignore the warning

Answer (score 0):

In you `info.plist` file, add `afnvision` under `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]